# Macro stop working after x number of lines

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code running perfectly to loop through multiple executive workbooks to copy and paste onto this Master workbook. It will look at till the last row of the respective executive workbook

```
readLastCellNameSheet = ExecutiveWorkBook.Sheets("Summary").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

Then paste accordingly to the Masterworkbook.
 However, when I inserted my 4000 rows of data, only 3000 rows are inserted into this Master workbook. Below is the complete code for reference. I have multiple executive workbooks with different rows that needs to be copied into the Master workbook. Everything worked fine until it stops at row 3000. Any suggestions?

```
Sub UpdateDate_Click()

Dim readLastCell As Long
Dim readLastCellNameSheet As Long
Dim billNumber
Dim SheetName As String
Dim billNumberNamesheet As Long
Dim ExecutiveWorkBookPath As String
Dim excelFilePath
Dim ExecutiveWorkBook As Workbook
Dim MainTemplate As String

MainTemplate = ThisWorkbook.Name

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master").Unprotect "12345+"
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master").Range("R1:AV20000").Locked = False
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master").Range("R4:AV20000").Value = ""


'ChDir Defaulth path
excelFilePath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path + "\"
Application.EnableEvents = False
strFilename = Dir(excelFilePath & "\*xlsm")


Do While strFilename <> ""
    'Set variable equal to opened workbook
        If InStr(strFilename, "Executive") > 0 Then
            Set ExecutiveWorkBook = Workbooks.Open(excelFilePath & strFilename, ReadOnly:=True)
            ExecutiveWorkBook.Worksheets("Summary").Unprotect "12345+"
            ExecutiveWorkBook.Worksheets("Summary").Range("A1:Q22000").Locked = False

            readLastCell = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            readLastCellNameSheet = ExecutiveWorkBook.Sheets("Summary").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

                For x = 4 To readLastCellNameSheet
                cell = "A" & x
                billNumber = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master").Range(cell).Value

                       If Len(billNumber) = 0 Then Exit For

                             For N = 4 To readLastCellNameSheet
                            cell = "A" & N
                            billNumberNamesheet = ExecutiveWorkBook.Worksheets("Summary").Range(cell).Value
                            If Len(billNumberNamesheet) = 0 Then Exit For

                            If billNumberNamesheet = billNumber Then
                                cell = "R" & N & ":" & "AV" & N
                                copycell = "R" & x & ":" & "AV" & x
                                ExecutiveWorkBook.Worksheets("Summary").Range(cell).Copy
                                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master").Range(copycell).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll

                            End If

                             Next N

                Next x
                        ExecutiveWorkBook.Worksheets("Summary").Range("A1:Q22000").Locked = True
                        ExecutiveWorkBook.Sheets("Summary").Protect "12345+", True, True
                        'ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master").Range("R1:AV20000").Locked = True
                        'ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master").Protect "12345+", True, True
                        ' CLOSE THE SOURCE FILE.
                        ExecutiveWorkBook.Close savechanges:=False   ' FALSE - DON'T SAVE THE SOURCE FILE.
        Else

        End If



'to get next file name
strFilename = Dir
Loop
Application.EnableEvents = True
MsgBox "Updated Succesully"
End Sub
```

Comment: you can check the value of `readLastCellNameSheet` before loop with `MsgBox`

Comment: @shibormot THANK YOUUU! It works! Sorry for the late response. Project put on hold for a while.